# Cocoa Touch Framework & CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to use `CoreData` inside my Cocoa Touch Framework. I create a simple project as an example: 
https://github.com/JakubMazur/SO41698466

Basically I do it in steps:

1. Create a framework with Unit Tests
2. Add `CoreData` to project `someDataModel`
3. Fill `CoreData` with some dummy Entity and change module to `Current Product Module`
4. Then I created `SomeClass` to start with and it's basically called
   :

.

```
public class func entityCreation() {
    Entity(context: CoreDataClass().persistentContainer.viewContext)
}
```

So with this `lazy` autogenerated code from CoreData this should create model.

5. In test I wrote:

.

```
func testExample() {
    SomeClass.entityCreation()
}
```

6. And fire the test
7. In `CoreDataClass` I put a breakpoint below line:
   `let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "someDataModel")` and then I see in console:

> [error] error:  Failed to load model named someDataModel
>   CoreData: error:  Failed to load model named someDataModel

So I have a 2 questions:

1. Is it possible to include Core Data inside framework
2. If 1 is true maybe I should use different `NSPersistentContainer` name? There is a way to check what should I put there?

Download a project here: https://github.com/JakubMazur/SO41698466

**Solution Found And Added below**

```
let modelURL = Bundle(for: type(of: self)).url(forResource: "someDataModel", withExtension: "momd")! 
let managedObjectModel = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL) 
let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "someDataModel", managedObjectModel: managedObjectModel!)
```

Comment: This seems harder than it should be to fix. NSPersistentContainer doesn't seem able to find the model in the main bundle, presumably due to the fact you're building a framework. You can get over that hurdle by finding and specifying the model yourself, then using the `name: managedObjectModel:` initialiser for NSPersistentContainer, but then you hit a different problem...

Comment: Ha, that was great clue @jrturton! Of course that is not a main Bundle. I fixed it with: `let modelURL = Bundle(for: type(of: self)).url(forResource: "someDataModel", withExtension: "momd")!
        let managedObjectModel = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL)
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "someDataModel", managedObjectModel: managedObjectModel!)` Thanks!

Comment: I then got invalid entity description warnings and I realised I needed to go back to work, sorry...

Answer (score 14):

## TLDR;

Apple recommends that you subclass `NSPersistentContainer` in your framework. If you do this then the framework which the subclass is defined in will be searched.

So you can simply:

```
final class PersistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer { }
```

Then use `PersistentContainer` rather than `NSPersistentContainer` in your framework.

## Explanation

The `name` initializer only searches through the main bundle.

To find the managed object model in a different framework you can get the model URL as suggested in the comments.

However, as an alternative, you can also subclass the `NSPersistentContainer` in your framework, then the `name` initializer will work.

Here is an excerpt from the WWDC `Core Data Best Practices` video:

> ... let's say we want to factor our model layer into its own
>   framework.
>
> We can do that by creating a new framework target in Xcode and moving
>   our code into it.
>
> It's all super easy, but when we move our model into the new target,
>   in the built product, targets move from the app into the new
>   framework, which is what's supposed to happen, but now
>   NSPersistentContainer doesn't know where to find our model anymore.
>
> This is because it only checks the main bundle by default.
>
> Why stop there?
>
> Well, searching all of the app's bundles could get really slow for a
>   complicated app and it's not a cost you want to pay every time you
>   spin up a stack.
>
> How do we fix this?
>
> Well, we could resuscitate the model out of the framework bundle
>   ourselves and use one of the container's other initializers, like one
>   that takes an explicit managed object model, but NSPersistentContainer
>   actually has a way for you to change which bundle it searches.
>
> See, NSPersistentContainer knows when it's been subclassed and will
>   use the type of the subclass as a hint when it looks for the model.
>
> All we need to do to take advantage of this is to create a subclass.
>
> It doesn't even need to have anything in it.
>
> Then, any code setting up through the container that wants to use our
>   model can just adopt that subclass and the persistent container will
>   check in our frameworks bundle for our model instead.

https://asciiwwdc.com/2018/sessions/224

Comment: Subclassed the `NSPersistentContainer` and now my unit tests are running like a charm. Thanks for the explanation.